# Duplicate primary key in laravel DB::table('mytable')->inset($data)

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

This is a typical case when my app receive 150 transaction to sametime kind of and app crash by duplicate in primary key

My problem is that i can't change column ID integer to autoincrement because i generate this ID for it is save ID in "orders" table and next save this ID in "order details" table, all is controler by code

i thinked that DB::beginTransaction() it will block table until to finish first inbound transaction but it not working.....

Is possible that solution will be implement queue message but in this moment i cant have the time for this.... i need a middle or temporary fix

Pls any idea?

features

- Laravel 7.0
- postgres 12
- load test K6

code:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$id = Orders::withTrashed()->max('id');
$id = $id + 1;
$data["id"] = $id 
.
.
.
DB::table('orders')->insert($data);

for ($x = 0; count($data["details"]) > $x; $x++) {
   $data["details"][$x]["id"] = $id;
}
DB::table('orders_details')->insert($data["details"]);
DB::commit();
```

This is error:

```
to Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "order_pkey"
```

Comment: Use AUTO_INCREMENT with LAST_INSERT_ID inside the transaction. Also, show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use auto-increment and use it like this

```
$order = new Order();
// Fill the order object
$order->save();
// Now you have order saved. you will have its id. 
// Use that to create details record.
$order_detail = new OrderDetail();
$order_detail->order_id = $order->id;
// Fill rest of the object
$order_detail->save();
```

If you still don't want to use auto-increment for whatever reason, instead of using int for id use UUID. It will be unique for all rows.

Comment: Uhmmm UUID is a good option but i have 1000 records in table orders and 3500 records in table orders_detail.... how make this change?

Comment: Try to use auto-increment ID like you already have. That works for very high-load servers. If it is not working for you, you are doing something wrong. UUIDs could work but they shouldn't be used for relations.

Comment: yes, i think that i wil can change to autoincrement with DB::table('orders')->insertGetId(...)